# Sound frequency and power

Tags: energy, acoustics, frequency, power

Although I have studied physics I am not clear on this question: Given that two (or more) sound waves have the same amplitude does the power they carry depend on frequency? What about electrical AC signals? I seem to be missing something...

Comment: The intensity (power per unit area)  is proportional to frequency squared for sound and for ac signals..  http://physics.info/intensity/